# Integrating redux-offline with Angular 5

Tags: angular, redux, angular5, offline

I am trying to make up my mind on how to write an angular web app that is able to work (read and write) under offline conditions.

I've seen that react-offline is a pretty good solution for my problem.

However, I have to write this app in Angular, so my question is how can I integrate the two?

I'm aware of angular-redux/store, but can it work with redux-offline? I don't want to reinvent the wheel...

Another question is whether ngrx gives me some offline capabilities too? What it lacks in comparison to redux-offline?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about the same thing and unfortunately I don't think that there's any offline direct support with ngrx right now (opened an [issue](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/325) a while ago but nothing yet).

That said, Angular can help you setup a service worker very quickly and easily, which means your app could be **available** offline. But you'll still have to manage the synchronisation on your own.

With the rise of PWA, I hope that'll have a better support for offline apps soon. In the meantime, ngrx has a single store and it's very easy to save it within local storage. So you could probably come up with something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what about using redux-offline instead in angular-redux/store? Is it much work?

Comment: @maxime1992 is there any solutions/tricks to deal with offline pwa (read & write) like redux-offline using ngrx ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know